How to go to .svelte component on control + left click instead of type definition in VSCode?
I'm using a monorepo with an npm workspace used as a global library.
When using components from this library, when I control + click (on VSCode) on one of them (.svelte component) on the import, it leads me xxx.d.ts (xxx being the name of the component), but I'd like to find a way for it to bring me to xxx.svelte
Is there a way to achieve this?
